# Sharepoint 2010 Managed Metadata - unable to get Term from TermSet

Tags: metadata, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

Having a really aggravating problem using Managed Metadata in SP2010 where I can get a Taxonomy Session, Term Store and Term set fine, but when I try to retrieve a term from the term set, I get a TermStoreOperationException which says that it "failed to read from or write to database".

Does anyone have any idea as to why I can get the Term Set but not the terms? I can't quite understand why when they all reside in the same database I can get the set but not the terms within it.

The code I'm using is below:

```
  TaxonomySession txSession = new TaxonomySession(site, true);

  TermStore termStore = txSession.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;                

  TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(TermSetId);
  TermCollection termCollection = termSet.GetTerms("My Term", true);  //exception thrown on this line.
```

Any ideas or insight or solutions would be really appreciated.

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get around this by getting the Term just by using the indexer on the Term Set:

```
 TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(txField.TermSetId);
 Term myTerm = termSet.Terms["My Term"]);
```

I'm not sure why .GetTerms() doesn't work - it might be because SP2010 is still not RTM and it's meant to be an internal method, or some other mysterious reason beyond my comprehension...